# JavaScript : group by

Tags: javascript, group-by, count

I have a result variable composed of 3 lists :

```
var result = {
type: [a,a,b,c,d,a,a,b],
program : [P1, P1, P2, P1, P2, P2, P2, P1],
reference : [ref1,ref2,ref3,...,ref8]}
```

I want to group my reference by type and program to obtain a dataset like this :

```
programme type count

P1 a 2

P1 b 1

P1 d 1

P2 a 2

P2 b 1 

P2 d 1
```

If someone have a solution to do this

Thanks in advance !

Comment: are you using SQL? i often do this in backend, because we can do that with SQL group by

Comment: Is there any relevance to the reference array here? What is the data structure you want as output (in JavaScript syntax)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function that gets the data and the list of columnnames to group by. Then keep a running count per group, where a group can be identified by the group keys (serialised from array to JSON):

```js
function groupByAndCount(data, ...keys) {
    const {length} = keys;
    return Object.values(data[keys[0]].reduce((acc, _, i) => {
        const group = keys.map(key => data[key][i]);
        (acc[JSON.stringify(group)] ??= [...group, 0])[length]++;
        return acc;
    }, {}));
}

const data = {
  type:      ["a",   "a",   "b",   "c",   "d",   "a",   "a",   "b"   ],
  program:   ["P1",  "P1",  "P2",  "P1",  "P2",  "P2",  "P2",  "P1"  ],
  reference: ["ref1","ref2","ref3","ref4","ref5","ref6","ref7","ref8"]
}

const result = groupByAndCount(data, "program", "type");
console.log(result);
```

If you want the output to have a similar structure as the input object, then:

```js
function groupByAndCount(data, ...keys) {
    const {length} = keys;
    const groups = Object.values(data[keys[0]].reduce((acc, _, i) => {
        const group = keys.map(key => data[key][i]);
        (acc[JSON.stringify(group)] ??= [...group, 0])[length]++;
        return acc;
    }, {}));
    return Object.fromEntries(keys.concat("count").map((key, i) =>
        [key, groups.map(group => group[i])]
    ));
}

const data = {
  type:      ["a",   "a",   "b",   "c",   "d",   "a",   "a",   "b"   ],
  program:   ["P1",  "P1",  "P2",  "P1",  "P2",  "P2",  "P2",  "P1"  ],
  reference: ["ref1","ref2","ref3","ref4","ref5","ref6","ref7","ref8"]
}

const result = groupByAndCount(data, "program", "type");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create matched pairs of the types and programs (in this case using the zip function) you can then loop through these pairs and group them in a fairly normal way.

```js
const result = {
  types: ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
  programs: ['P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P1'],
};

const zip = (array1, array2) => {
  let zipped = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < Math.max(array1.length, array2.length); i++) {
    zipped.push([array1[i], array2[i]]);
  }
  
  return zipped;
};

const collate = (data) => {
  let grouped = {};
  
  for(const [type, program] of zip(data.types, data.programs)) {
    grouped[type + '-' + program] ??= { program, type, count: 0 };
    grouped[type + '-' + program].count++;
  }
  
  return Object.values(grouped).sort(
    (a, b) => a.program.localeCompare(b.program) || a.type.localeCompare(b.type)
  );
};

console.log(collate(result));
```